# How To Save Comma Separated Value in Laravel From For each Loop

Tags: laravel, group-concat

I am getting nearest to the driver id by using below laravel code

```
 $nearest_car = DriverLocation::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos(radians( longitude ) - radians('.$pickup_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'))
->having('distance', '<=', 5)->where('driver_location.status','Online')->where('driver_location.car_id',$car_id);
```

and saving request details with below code including above nearest driver id

```
 $request  = new Request;
        $request->user_id          =   $rider_id;
        $request->pickup_latitude  =   $pickup_latitude;
        $request->pickup_longitude =   $pickup_longitude;
        $request->drop_latitude    =   $drop_latitude;
        $request->drop_longitude   =   $drop_longitude;
        $request->driver_id        =   $nearest_car->user_id;
        $request->car_id           =   $car_id;
        $request->pickup_location  =   $pickup_location;
        $request->drop_location    =   $drop_location;
        $request->payment_mode   =   $payment_method_store;
```

what I want to do is to get multiple nearest distinct driver id (like 5 to 10 nearest id) and save all the id's as comma separated value in `driver_id` column. all above details are same for all drivers.Only need to get all nearest driver id's and save them as comma separated value like below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `DriverLocation` model has `user_id`, apply the following to get comma separated `user_id`:

```php
$nearest_driver_ids = DriverLocation::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos(radians( longitude ) - radians('.$pickup_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'))
    ->having('distance', '<=', 5)
    ->where('driver_location.status', 'Online')
    ->where('driver_location.car_id', $car_id)
    ->get()
    ->implode('user_id', ',');
```

The `implode` method will extract only `user_id` from the list of fetched `DriverLocation` and finally join them with `,` to form a new string.